# golang querying database using Gorm and returning json in http response

Tags: json, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm new to Go and am using Gorm to query my postgres database but am having trouble returning my data in a dictionary format, where the pokemon's type serves as a key to an array of all the pokemon of that type

> json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []models.Pokemon

here's my code:

```
type Pokemon struct {
    Name   string   `db:"name"`
    Type   string   `db:"type"`
}

pokemonTypes := [6]string{
    "fire",
    "electric",
    "water",
    "grass",
}

var retData struct {
   Poke []Pokemon
}

m := make(map[string][]Pokemon)

for _, t := range pokemonTypes {
    pokemon := DB.Where(&Pokemon{Type: t}).Find(&retData.Poke)
    p, _ := json.Marshal(pokemon)
    err = json.Unmarshal(p, &retData.Poke)  // getting error here
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    m[category] = retData.Poke
}

data, _ := json.Marshal(m) 
w.Write(data)  // http repsonse
```

I have this in my database

```
name       | type
----------------------
pikachu    | electric
charmander | fire
blaziken   | fire
venusaur   | grass
treeko     | grass
squirtle   | water
```

I want to return data in this json format

```
{
  “electric”: [
    {"name": "pikachu", "type": "electric"},
  ],
  "fire": [
    {"name": "charmander", "type": "fire"},
    {"name": "blaziken", "type": "fire"}
  ],
  "grass": [
    {"name": "venusaur", "type": "grass"},
    {"name": "treeko", "type": "grass"},
  ],
  "water": [
    {"name": "squirtle", "type": "water"},
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DB.Where(&Pokemon{Type: t}).Find(&retData.Poke)` esentially returns back the `*db` pointer which you can use to chain further methods.
You're already deserializing postgre rows into your struct slice when you do `.Find(&retData.Poke)`. Thus, `pokemon` isn't actually what you think it is.

The only thing left now is to chain `.Find()` with a `.Error()` so that you can return and check any error in your query. Just like this :

```
for _, t := range pokemonTypes {
    err := DB.Where(&Pokemon{Type: t}).Find(&retData.Poke).Error()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    p, _ := json.Marshal(retData.Poke)
    err = json.Unmarshal(p, &retData.Poke) 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    m[category] = retData.Poke
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks man! turns out i don't need to marshal/unmarshal too since the data is in retData.Poke already